# How to render line plot for array with sparse data in d3.js without data pre-processing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This problem can be solved by pre-processing the data (e.g. inserting null values and using line.defined() function of the d3.js), but I am looking for solution that does not require data pre-processing.

Let's say we have array of objects:

```
 {time_stamp: "2014-10-05 10:15:00", value: 45}
 {time_stamp: "2014-10-05 10:30:00", value: 50}
 {time_stamp: "2014-10-05 10:45:00", value: 30}
 {time_stamp: "2014-10-05 12:30:00", value: 23}
 {time_stamp: "2014-10-05 12:45:00", value: 28}
 {time_stamp: "2014-10-05 13:00:00", value: 42}
 {time_stamp: "2014-10-06 10:15:00", value: 45}
 {time_stamp: "2014-10-06 10:30:00", value: 50}
 {time_stamp: "2014-10-06 10:45:00", value: 30}
 {time_stamp: "2014-10-06 12:30:00", value: 23}
 {time_stamp: "2014-10-06 12:45:00", value: 28}
 {time_stamp: "2014-10-06 13:00:00", value: 42}
```

As you can see the data are scattered over the time line and most of the time there are no data at all. I am trying to plot these values using line, which (of course) connects the "end" points of each "mini-series".
The X scale is defined as:

```
d3.time.scale().....
```

so it covers the whole domain without any problem.

The trouble (and reason why I'm asking this question) is that the data spans over years, so generating null values for every 15 minutes interval is quite a lot of data. Also this is only one type of data displayed in the app, the other data types have significantly less "missing" values.

So, the question is, is there a way how to plot such array without need for data pre-processing?

Comment: Using `line.defined()` isn't preprocessing. It sounds like this is the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Well, to use `line.defined()` you have to have some data in the array (e.g. value=null for some time_stamp) ... that is not this case. By pre-processing I mean necessity of data insertion into the original array.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I can't think of any other way to do it though. I guess you could draw individual line segments and figure out whether something is "connected" this way, but that would likely become quite messy and would involve at least some degree of preprocessing as well.